# Не выводится картинка thymeleaf

Tags: java, spring, thymeleaf

В базе хранятся картинки, которые передаю в виде списка, но возникает ошибка.

Мой **PostController**

```
package ru.monkeyTeam.demo.controller;

import lombok.RequiredArgsConstructor;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;
import org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartFile;
import ru.monkeyTeam.demo.models.Image;
import ru.monkeyTeam.demo.models.Post;
import ru.monkeyTeam.demo.services.PostService;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.List;

@Controller
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class PostController {

    private final PostService postService;

    @GetMapping("/")
    public String posts(@RequestParam(name = "title", required = false) String title, Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("posts", postService.listPost(title));
        return "posts";
    }

    @GetMapping("/post/creat")
    public String pageCreatPost(Model model) {
        return "post_creat";
    }

    @PostMapping("/post/creat")
    public String createPost(@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file, Post post) throws IOException {
        postService.savePost(post, file);
        return "redirect:/";
    }

    @PostMapping("/post/delete/{id}")
    public String deletePost(@PathVariable Long id) {
        postService.deletePost(id);
        return "redirect:/";
    }

    @GetMapping("post/{id}")
    public String postInfo(@PathVariable Long id, Model model) {
        Post post = postService.getPostById(id);
        List<Image> images = post.getImages();
        model.addAttribute("post", post);
        model.addAttribute("images", images);
        return "post_info";
    }
}
```

**ImageController**

```
package ru.monkeyTeam.demo.controller;

import lombok.RequiredArgsConstructor;
import org.springframework.core.io.InputStreamResource;
import org.springframework.http.MediaType;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;
import ru.monkeyTeam.demo.models.Image;
import ru.monkeyTeam.demo.repositories.ImageRepository;

import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;

@RestController
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class ImageController {
    private final ImageRepository imageRepository;
    @GetMapping("/images/{id}")
    private ResponseEntity<?> getImageById(@PathVariable Long id) {
        Image image = imageRepository.findById(id).orElse(null);
        return ResponseEntity.ok()
                .header("fileName", image.getOriginalFileName())
                .contentType(MediaType.valueOf(image.getContentType()))
                .contentLength(Long.parseLong(image.getSize()))
                .body(new InputStreamResource(new ByteArrayInputStream(image.getBytes())));
    }

}
```

Отображение

```
   <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title th:text="${title}"></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
          integrity="sha384-rbsA2VBKQhggwzxH7pPCaAqO46MgnOM80zW1RWuH61DGLwZJEdK2Kadq2F9CUG65" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<body>
<header th:insert="blocks/header :: header"></header>

<div class="jumbotron">
    <div th:each="img : ${images}">
        <img th:src="@{'/images/' + ${img.id}}" alt="img" class="img-thumbnail" height="80pxa"/>
    </div>
    <h1 th:text="${post.title}" class="display-4"></h1>
    <p th:text="${post.title}" class="lead"></p>
    <hr class="my-4">
    <p class="lead">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Загрузить изображение в модель</button>
    </p>
    <a href="/">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary">Назад</button>
    </a><br>
    <form th:action="@{'/post/delete/{id}' (id=${post.id})}" th:method="post">
        <br>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-secondary">Удалить</button>
    </form>
</div>

<footer th:insert="blocks/footer :: footer"></footer>
</body>
</html>
```

Возникает такая ошибка

```
This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.

Fri Apr 28 23:28:41 MSK 2023
There was an unexpected error (type=Internal Server Error, status=500).
An error happened during template parsing (template: "class path resource [templates/post_info.html]")
org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateInputException: An error happened during template parsing (template: "class path resource [templates/post_info.html]")
    at org.thymeleaf.templateparser.markup.AbstractMarkupTemplateParser.parse(AbstractMarkupTemplateParser.java:241)
    at org.thymeleaf.templateparser.markup.AbstractMarkupTemplateParser.parseStandalone(AbstractMarkupTemplateParser.java:100)
    at org.thymeleaf.engine.TemplateManager.parseAndProcess(TemplateManager.java:666)
    at org.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine.process(TemplateEngine.java:1103)
    at org.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine.process(TemplateEngine.java:1077)
    at org.thymeleaf.spring6.view.ThymeleafView.renderFragment(ThymeleafView.java:372)
    at org.thymeleaf.spring6.view.ThymeleafView.render(ThymeleafView.java:192)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1415)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processDispatchResult(DispatcherServlet.java:1159)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1098)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:974)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1011)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:903)
    at jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:564)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:885)
    at jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:658)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:205)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:51)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:174)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:174)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:174)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:174)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:166)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:90)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:482)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:115)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:93)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:341)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:390)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:63)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:894)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1741)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:52)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1589)
Caused by: org.attoparser.ParseException: Exception evaluating SpringEL expression: "images.size()" (template: "post_info" - line 18, col 9)
    at org.attoparser.MarkupParser.parseDocument(MarkupParser.java:393)
    at org.attoparser.MarkupParser.parse(MarkupParser.java:257)
    at org.thymeleaf.templateparser.markup.AbstractMarkupTemplateParser.parse(AbstractMarkupTemplateParser.java:230)
    ... 48 more
Caused by: org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateProcessingException: Exception evaluating SpringEL expression: "images.size()" (template: "post_info" - line 18, col 9)
    at org.thymeleaf.spring6.expression.SPELVariableExpressionEvaluator.evaluate(SPELVariableExpressionEvaluator.java:292)
    at org.thymeleaf.standard.expression.VariableExpression.executeVariableExpression(VariableExpression.java:166)
    at org.thymeleaf.standard.expression.SimpleExpression.executeSimple(SimpleExpression.java:66)
    at org.thymeleaf.standard.expression.Expression.execute(Expression.java:109)
    at org.thymeleaf.standard.expression.Expression.execute(Expression.java:138)
    at org.thymeleaf.standard.processor.AbstractStandardExpressionAttributeTagProcessor.doProcess(AbstractStandardExpressionAttributeTagProcessor.java:144)
    at org.thymeleaf.processor.element.AbstractAttributeTagProcessor.doProcess(AbstractAttributeTagProcessor.java:74)
    at org.thymeleaf.processor.element.AbstractElementTagProcessor.process(AbstractElementTagProcessor.java:95)
    at org.thymeleaf.util.ProcessorConfigurationUtils$ElementTagProcessorWrapper.process(ProcessorConfigurationUtils.java:633)
    at org.thymeleaf.engine.ProcessorTemplateHandler.handleOpenElement(ProcessorTemplateHandler.java:1314)
    at org.thymeleaf.engine.TemplateHandlerAdapterMarkupHandler.handleOpenElementEnd(TemplateHandlerAdapterMarkupHandler.java:304)
    at org.thymeleaf.templateparser.markup.InlinedOutputExpressionMarkupHandler$InlineMarkupAdapterPreProcessorHandler.handleOpenElementEnd(InlinedOutputExpressionMarkupHandler.java:278)
    at org.thymeleaf.standard.inline.OutputExpressionInlinePreProcessorHandler.handleOpenElementEnd(OutputExpressionInlinePreProcessorHandler.java:186)
    at org.thymeleaf.templateparser.markup.InlinedOutputExpressionMarkupHandler.handleOpenElementEnd(InlinedOutputExpressionMarkupHandler.java:124)
    at org.attoparser.HtmlElement.handleOpenElementEnd(HtmlElement.java:109)
    at org.attoparser.HtmlMarkupHandler.handleOpenElementEnd(HtmlMarkupHandler.java:297)
    at org.attoparser.MarkupEventProcessorHandler.handleOpenElementEnd(MarkupEventProcessorHandler.java:402)
    at org.attoparser.ParsingElementMarkupUtil.parseOpenElement(ParsingElementMarkupUtil.java:159)
    at org.attoparser.MarkupParser.parseBuffer(MarkupParser.java:710)
    at org.attoparser.MarkupParser.parseDocument(MarkupParser.java:301)
    ... 50 more
Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException: Unable to access lob stream
    at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.java.PrimitiveByteArrayJavaType.wrap(PrimitiveByteArrayJavaType.java:136)
    at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.java.PrimitiveByteArrayJavaType.wrap(PrimitiveByteArrayJavaType.java:29)
    at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.jdbc.BlobJdbcType$1.doExtract(BlobJdbcType.java:62)
    at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.jdbc.BasicExtractor.extract(BasicExtractor.java:44)
    at org.hibernate.sql.results.jdbc.internal.JdbcValuesResultSetImpl.readCurrentRowValues(JdbcValuesResultSetImpl.java:262)
    at org.hibernate.sql.results.jdbc.internal.JdbcValuesResultSetImpl.advance(JdbcValuesResultSetImpl.java:243)
    at org.hibernate.sql.results.jdbc.internal.JdbcValuesResultSetImpl.processNext(JdbcValuesResultSetImpl.java:84)
    at org.hibernate.sql.results.jdbc.internal.AbstractJdbcValues.next(AbstractJdbcValues.java:29)
    at org.hibernate.sql.results.internal.RowProcessingStateStandardImpl.next(RowProcessingStateStandardImpl.java:62)
    at org.hibernate.sql.results.spi.ListResultsConsumer.consume(ListResultsConsumer.java:178)
    at org.hibernate.sql.results.spi.ListResultsConsumer.consume(ListResultsConsumer.java:33)
    at org.hibernate.sql.exec.internal.JdbcSelectExecutorStandardImpl.doExecuteQuery(JdbcSelectExecutorStandardImpl.java:362)
    at org.hibernate.sql.exec.internal.JdbcSelectExecutorStandardImpl.executeQuery(JdbcSelectExecutorStandardImpl.java:168)
    at org.hibernate.sql.exec.internal.JdbcSelectExecutorStandardImpl.list(JdbcSelectExecutorStandardImpl.java:93)
    at org.hibernate.sql.exec.spi.JdbcSelectExecutor.list(JdbcSelectExecutor.java:31)
    at org.hibernate.loader.ast.internal.CollectionLoaderSingleKey.load(CollectionLoaderSingleKey.java:117)
    at org.hibernate.persister.collection.AbstractCollectionPersister.initialize(AbstractCollectionPersister.java:668)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultInitializeCollectionEventListener.onInitializeCollection(DefaultInitializeCollectionEventListener.java:75)
    at org.hibernate.event.service.internal.EventListenerGroupImpl.fireEventOnEachListener(EventListenerGroupImpl.java:127)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.initializeCollection(SessionImpl.java:1697)
    at org.hibernate.collection.spi.AbstractPersistentCollection.lambda$initialize$3(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:617)
    at org.hibernate.collection.spi.AbstractPersistentCollection.withTemporarySessionIfNeeded(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:265)
    at org.hibernate.collection.spi.AbstractPersistentCollection.initialize(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:615)
    at org.hibernate.collection.spi.AbstractPersistentCollection.read(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:136)
    at org.hibernate.collection.spi.AbstractPersistentCollection.lambda$readSize$0(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:163)
    at org.hibernate.collection.spi.AbstractPersistentCollection.withTemporarySessionIfNeeded(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:265)
    at org.hibernate.collection.spi.AbstractPersistentCollection.readSize(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:148)
    at org.hibernate.collection.spi.PersistentBag.size(PersistentBag.java:355)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:104)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:578)
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.support.ReflectiveMethodExecutor.execute(ReflectiveMethodExecutor.java:139)
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.MethodReference.getValueInternal(MethodReference.java:112)
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.MethodReference$MethodValueRef.getValue(MethodReference.java:380)
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.CompoundExpression.getValueInternal(CompoundExpression.java:93)
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.SpelNodeImpl.getValue(SpelNodeImpl.java:114)
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.standard.SpelExpression.getValue(SpelExpression.java:338)
    at org.thymeleaf.spring6.expression.SPELVariableExpressionEvaluator.evaluate(SPELVariableExpressionEvaluator.java:265)
    ... 69 more
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: Большие объекты не могут использоваться в режиме авто-подтверждения (auto-commit).
    at org.postgresql.largeobject.LargeObjectManager.open(LargeObjectManager.java:244)
    at org.postgresql.largeobject.LargeObjectManager.open(LargeObjectManager.java:230)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.AbstractBlobClob.getLo(AbstractBlobClob.java:288)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.AbstractBlobClob.getBinaryStream(AbstractBlobClob.java:127)
    at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.java.PrimitiveByteArrayJavaType.wrap(PrimitiveByteArrayJavaType.java:133)
    ... 105 more
```

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте указать тип в `Image` сущности для поля `bytes`:

```java
@Entity
public class Image {
// ...
    @Lob
    @Type(type = "org.hibernate.type.ImageType")
    private byte[] bytes;
}
```

и/или изменить тип колонки в базе на `bytea` (массив байт), который позволяет хранить файлы размером до 1 ГБ.

См. [Eng SO: Large Objects may not be used in auto-commit mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3164072/)

Comment: что если "type" подчеркивает красным?

Comment: По идее эта аннотация находится в пакете [`org.hibernate.annotations`](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.2/javadocs/org/hibernate/annotations/Type.html), для которой может потребоваться указание [отдельной зависимости](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate/hibernate-annotations/3.5.6-Final)